# Concat in function

Tags: sql-server

I've an issue when I try to create a function from a working concat select

Here the function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.afEvrGetConsequencesConcat
(@id_evr int,@type_evr int)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

    declare @result varchar(max)
    set @result= ''

IF @type_evr = 0 
BEGIN

    SELECT @result = @result + (case when (CEV.ID_CON is null) then CEV.NOM_CEV else CON.NOM_CON end) + ' ; '  
    from T_CONSEQUENCE_EVRP CEV 
    left join T_CONSEQUENCE CON on CEV.id_con=CON.id_con
    WHERE CEV.id_evr = @id_evr

END

IF @type_evr = 1
BEGIN

        SELECT DISTINCT @result = @result + isnull(NOM_PHR,'') + ' ; '  
        FROM T_EVRP EVR
        INNER JOIN T_EVR_CHIM CHIM on EVR.ID_EVR=CHIM.ID_EVR
        INNER JOIN T_PRODUIT PROD on CHIM.ID_PROD=PROD.ID_PROD
        INNER JOIN T_PRODUIT_PHRASE_R PROD_PHR on PROD.ID_PROD=PROD_PHR.ID_PROD
        INNER JOIN T_PHRASE_R PHR on PROD_PHR.ID_PHR=PHR.ID_PHR
        WHERE TYPE_EVR=1 AND EVR.id_evr = @id_evr AND PHR.flag_consequence = 1

        UNION 

        SELECT DISTINCT @result = @result + isnull(nom_cons_txt,'') +' ; '  
        FROM T_EVRP EVR
        INNER JOIN T_EVR_CHIM CHIM on EVR.ID_EVR=CHIM.ID_EVR
        INNER JOIN T_PRODUIT PROD on CHIM.ID_PROD=PROD.ID_PROD
        INNER JOIN t_consequence_txt PROD_CONS on PROD.ID_PROD=PROD_CONS.ID_PROD
        WHERE TYPE_EVR=1 AND EVR.id_evr = @id_evr AND PROD.transverse_prod = 1

END

    RETURN @result

END
GO
```

And the message error is 'Msg 444, Niveau 16, État 2, Procédure afEvrGetConsequencesConcat, Ligne 23
Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client.'

The SELECT above works well outside a function. Each time, I got 1 varchar in @result, that match with the SELECT concat. And this similary function works well too :

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.afEvrGetControleConcat
(@id_evr int,@type_evr int,@type_ctrl int)
RETURNS varchar(8000)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @result varchar(8000)
    set @result= ''

    -- 0 tous
    -- 1 date + comm


    IF @type_ctrl = 0
    BEGIN   

        SELECT @result = @result + ( CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),date_ctr, 103) + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),isnull(valeur_mesure,'')) + ' - ' + isnull(unite_mesure,'') + ' - ' + com_ctr  ) + ' ;'
        FROM t_controle_exposition 
        WHERE id_evr = @id_evr

    END

    IF @type_ctrl = 1
    BEGIN   

        SELECT @result = @result + ( CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),date_ctr, 103) + ' - ' + com_ctr  ) + ' ;'
        FROM t_controle_exposition 
        WHERE id_evr = @id_evr

    END

    RETURN @result

END
GO
```

Then what is the problem ? By logic, I want return a varchar, not a table or any funky data. So I don't unterstand this error message.

Thank for your help.

EDIT: Add a temporary table and insert inside the result of UNION and concat next works well :)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.afEvrGetConsequencesConcat
(@id_evr int,@type_evr int)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

    declare @result varchar(max)
    set @result= ''
    declare @t as table (v varchar(max))

IF @type_evr = 0 
BEGIN

    SELECT @result = @result + (case when (CEV.ID_CON is null) then CEV.NOM_CEV else CON.NOM_CON end) + ' ; '  
    from T_CONSEQUENCE_EVRP CEV 
    left join T_CONSEQUENCE CON on CEV.id_con=CON.id_con
    WHERE CEV.id_evr = @id_evr

END

IF @type_evr = 1
BEGIN

        insert into @t 
        SELECT DISTINCT isnull(NOM_PHR,'') + ' ; '  
        FROM T_EVRP EVR
        INNER JOIN T_EVR_CHIM CHIM on EVR.ID_EVR=CHIM.ID_EVR
        INNER JOIN T_PRODUIT PROD on CHIM.ID_PROD=PROD.ID_PROD
        INNER JOIN T_PRODUIT_PHRASE_R PROD_PHR on PROD.ID_PROD=PROD_PHR.ID_PROD
        INNER JOIN T_PHRASE_R PHR on PROD_PHR.ID_PHR=PHR.ID_PHR
        WHERE TYPE_EVR=1 AND EVR.id_evr = @id_evr AND PHR.flag_consequence = 1

        UNION 

        SELECT DISTINCT isnull(nom_cons_txt,'') +' ; '  
        FROM T_EVRP EVR
        INNER JOIN T_EVR_CHIM CHIM on EVR.ID_EVR=CHIM.ID_EVR
        INNER JOIN T_PRODUIT PROD on CHIM.ID_PROD=PROD.ID_PROD
        INNER JOIN t_consequence_txt PROD_CONS on PROD.ID_PROD=PROD_CONS.ID_PROD
        WHERE TYPE_EVR=1 AND EVR.id_evr = @id_evr AND PROD.transverse_prod = 1

SELECT @result = @result + v FROM @t

END

    RETURN @result

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is to do with the UNION. Try running:

```
DECLARE @result varchar(max)

SELECT @result = 'test'

UNION 

SELECT @result = 'another'
```

You will get:

```
Msg 10734, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Variable assignment is not allowed in a statement containing a top level UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.
```

If you must do the UNION, you're going to have to return a table, otherwise come up with some other way without the UNION. This could explain why the second function works, as it doesn't have a UNION

Comment: yes, the issue was coming from UNION. I've added a tempory table and it is working :)